# odoo security and access rights issue

Tags: odoo

I am new in odoo development so writing module access and rights but facing some issue .here is error below, please help me

Exception: Module loading student_registration failed: file student_registration/security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:

No matching record found for external id 'student_registration_group_manager' in field 'Group'
No matching record found for external id 'student_registration_group_user' in field 'Group'
No matching record found for external id 'student_registration_group_manager' in field 'Group'
No matching record found for external id 'student_registration_group_user' in field 'Group'

Comment: Could you please add your manifest content (\_\_openerp\_\_.py or \_\_manifest\_\_.py) and your xml where these groups are "created"?

Answer (score 0):

if you have put the group in you xml data file and you have put this file in your `__openerp__.py` . you need respect the order of you xml ids in the files you cannot reference to xml id in a file that is not persed yet by the frame work.

Comment: Done ! its working now. Just applying rules to users to view records related to them not all records belongs to other users.

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

While giving access rights just make sure you keep the `< ir.model.access.csv >` file below the `< security.xml >`. It's because it won't be able to find the user groups specified in the " .CSV " file after it loads since the `< security.xml >` that have the group definitions are called second.

To address the issue, in ***openerp*.py**   or  **__manifest__.py**:

```
'data': [ 
        'security/security.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
....
]
```